# Maintain Page Scroll Position After Leaving Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

In ASP.NET/C#, I would like to preserve the page scroll position as a query string parameter and then when returning to the page load the scroll position from the query string parameter.

MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback and scrollTop are not sufficient when leaving the page and returning.

Comment: When you say returning to the page do you mean during the same session or anytime the page is loaded for the user?

Comment: Same session is fine.

Comment: Instead of passing the value in as a parameter have you considered storing it in a session variable which you check OnPageLoad?

Comment: That would work as well. Thanks.